# IE homepage periodically changes to MSN

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have IE 11, and every couple months, the homepage will revert to msn.com. I have no idea how or why. And it doesn't happen all the time, but frequent enough that it is annoying. This is my work computer, and we don't have any group policies that force msn.com as the homepage. What is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

As I was asking this question, I was looking through the registry for clues. I found a registry value called "Start Page Redirect Cache" that had msn.com listed. I believe this is why I only sometimes see msn.com as my homepage. I changed the value to match my homepage. If this doesn't fix the issue, I'll re-open this question.